# How to use someone else's firebase app for mine (it's from a tutorial)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

What should I do to use someone else's firebase application? I made a new firebase account with my bundle identifier , and replaced the googleserviceinfo file , but it's not working. What have I missed

**update**

This is not stealing or anything, I'm just following a YouTube tutorial and download the demo app he made , just wanna test it out with my database.

Comment: file a report to claim it as yours. if not approve then you're no good. or use their contact us for help.

Comment: @nferocious76 actually I just want to test it out

Comment: It is not possible to claim someone else work without agreement. you should create your own or buy their code. and there is no way to test it out.

Comment: @nferocious76 will it be possible if I copied all his code to a new project?

Comment: yes it is. that means you'll be the one to create your own bundle. but their code will not be accessible to you. ask them for it. there is no way to extract it from the publish app.

Comment: @nferocious76 I have their code , all of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129636/discussion-between-nferocious76-and-lasan).

Comment: @nferocious76 saw ur message on chat , yeah , I'm gonna try that too , thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue , all i had to do was go to the firebase console and enable email and password accounts in the auth section . Error was Firautherrorcodeoperationnotallowed 17006

Answer (score 1):

So it seems the people commenting think you want to 'steal' someone's app, while in reality you found some sample code which you want to test with your own data. If this is not correct disregard the info below.

To change someones sample code (which is set up with their firebase database data) you need to do these two things:

You need to replace the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file with a new one that you yourself generate in the Firebase Console.

Make sure the Bundle ID in your app matches the one you setup in the Firebase console.

Comment: Yeah , that describes all those down votes , got 4 down votes and 3 up , when someone has edited the question. Thank you for your answer+1 , i thought I had to put the link to database manually in someplace . But the app gets database link automatically using the googleserviceinfo file right ? Problem was database not connecting, everything else worked fine without an error .

Comment: @lasan yep that should do the trick. The plist takes cares of everything in terms of setting it up. Be sure to flag the answer as answered if this solved the problem for you. And let me know here if you run into any issues! Happy to help 

Comment: I did what u said , but still can't connect to the database , do I have to manually create a database with columns ? But with his plist and bundle id , it simulates fine , when i put mine , it says cant connect to the database , i ll send u the link to the code please check it if possible, means a lot

Comment: Bit.ly/chatappios is the link for the app , please try it with your firebase plist , and check that database problem, thats all i need ,

Comment: Did you create a new fire base project?

Comment: Yes i did , it didn't work , the link i sent u was from the demo app from the tutorial , it works well , but try changing the firebase account, Im using xcode 8